# Displaying multiple graphs from networkx in a table

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I've been playing around with the random graph feature of networkx as seen here with the Erdos-Renyi graph:

```
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n, p, seed=None, directed=False)
```

I can then draw the graph with

```
nx.draw
```

Is there a way, I can make a table of random graph images using nx.draw? I want to make a table of some sampled graphs with some labels. Is there a way to do this using Matlab plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correclty, you can use subplots to achieve what you want:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)

for ax in axes.ravel():
    G = nx.gnp_random_graph(10,10, seed=None, directed=False)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, ax=ax)
```

Edit:

You can change the size of the figure at instantiation, by using:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(10,10)) # default unit is inches.
```

You can change the size after the fact by doing:

```
fig.set_figwidth(10)
and 
fig.set_figheight(10)
```

you can access individual subplots if you have more than 1 row and more than 1 column, like so:

```
axes[row,column] # zero-indexed.
```

to add labels or other stuff, you can do:

```
axes[row,column].set_ylabel('blah')
axes[row,column].set_title('blubb')
```

to change the figure title you can do:

```
fig.suptitle('my fancy title')
```

If at the end your labels intersect or your figure looks otherwise messy, you can enforce tight layout:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with subplots.

Comment: This looks good, one thing to potentially ask you, it looks like that the line where you set ax=ax specifies the position of the drawing of the graph. But is there a way afterwards to adjust the size of the table and label the images?

Comment: Wait, I think you can label the graphs directly from nx.draw_networkx

Comment: @user135520 see my edit for some ideas. If you have something specific, let me know.